# Moving \sffamily to latex preamble

Tags: fonts, macros, preamble

I'm using `\rmfamily` and `\sffamily` to switch between two fonts in my document, one for sections and one for the rest of the text. However, I cant find a way to move my `\sffamily` command before `\begin{document}` and still have it apply to the text outside the section header. How can I include `\sffamily` in my preamble where it could do this?

```
\documentclass[{12pt}]{article}

%import font styles Play for headers and Lato for body
\usepackage{Play} 
\usepackage[defaultsans]{lato} 

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\rmfamily}{{}}{0em}{}

\begin{document}    

\sffamily
    
\section{Section}
words words words
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: doesn't `\usepackage[default]{lato}` do what you want? (without the \sffamily)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

%import font styles Play for headers and Lato for body
\usepackage{Play} 
\usepackage[defaultsans]{lato} 
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}%% <===== 

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\rmfamily}{{}}{0em}{}

\begin{document}    
    
    \section{Section}
    words words words
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `{}` are wrong here `\documentclass[{12pt}]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `default`, not `defaultsans`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%import font styles Play for headers and Lato for body
%\usepackage{Play}
\usepackage[default]{lato}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\rmfamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
words words words

\end{document}
```

[image]